# How to deal with NULL value while using DATEPART?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, isnull, datepart

I am using SQL 2008 R2 and I have used DATEPART in one of my select lines, this converts a date and time column to a decimal based on the time.

But I have some `NULL` values coming through that I would like to show as 0.  I have used `ISNULL` on other columns but unable to use it on this one because I don't know how to do it in conjunction with the DATEPART.

Please see below where I have used datepart but also want to change null values to 0.

```
DATEPART(hour, tblCarerContract.ContractHours) + (DATEPART(minute, tblCarerContract.ContractHours) / 60.0) as ContractHours
```

Can anybody help with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to go about this would be to use a [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) statement to change the nulls to 0.

Try something like this

```
COALESCE(DATEPART(hour, tblCarerContract.ContractHours), 0) + (COALESCE(DATEPART(minute, tblCarerContract.ContractHours), 0) / 60.0) as ContractHours
```

Comment: Hi Ian, Just tested it and it works perfect. thank you so much, this has been driving me nuts.  as you can see I am still very new to this.  Thank you again for your help !

Comment: I think it's actually better to use `ISNULL` since it actually gets rid of null-ness. `COALESCE` still returns a nullable type.